# Why a significant risk factor doesn't increase AUC-score/F1-metric?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, statistics, logistic-regression

I have a binary classification problem with 5K records and 60+ features/columns/variables. dataset is slighlt imbalanced with 33:67 class proportion

What I did was

**1st)**  Run a logistic regression (statsmodel) with all 60+ columns as input (meaning controlling confounders) and find out the significant risk factors (`p<0.0.5`) from result(`summary output`). Because I have to know that my risk factors are significant as well i.e causal modeling. Meaning build a predictive model on the basis of causal features. I say this because in a field like medical science/clinical studies, I believe it is also important to know the causal effect. I mean if you wish to publish in a journal, do you think we can just list the variables based on feature importance approach (results of which differ for each FS approach). Ofcourse, I find some common features across all feature selection algorithm. But is this enough to justify that this a meaningful predictor? Hence, I was hoping that `p-value` would convince and help people understand that this is significant predictor

**2nd)**  Use the identified `7 significant risk factors` to build a classification ML model

**3rd)**  It yielded an AUC of around 82% in test data (30% of split from full dataset)

Now my question is

**1)** Out of 7 significant factors identified, we already know 5 risk factors based on domain experience and literature. So we are considering the rest 2 as `new factors which we found`. Might be because we had a very good data collection strategy (meaning we collected data for new variables as well which previous literature didn't have)

**2)** But when I build a model with already known 5 features, it produces an AUC of `82.1`. When I include all the `7 significant features`, it still produces an AUC of `82.1-82.3`. Not much improvement. Why is this happening?

**3)** If it's of no use, how does `statsmodel` logistic regression identified them as significant feature (with `p<0.05`)?

**4)** I guess we can look at any metric. As my data is slightly imbalanced (`33:67` is the class proportion), I am using only metrics like `AUC` and `F1` score.

**5)** Should I balance the dataset because I am using `statsmodel Logistic regression` to identify the risk factors from the `summary` output? Because I use `tree based models` later to do the classification which can handle imbalance well, so I didn't balance.Basically what I am trying to know is even for `significant factor identification using statsmodel logistic regression, should I balance the dataset?

**6)** Can you let me know what is the problem here and how can I address this?

**7)** How much of an improvement in performance is considered as valid/meaningful to be considered as new findings?

**POST UPDATE**

You might wonder why do I have to do `Xgboost` when I do `logistic regression` in the first place. I do this because with `Logistic regression` yields only an `AUC` of 79-80 whereas `Xgboost` results with an AUC of `81-82`. Reason why I do `Logistic regression` in the first place is because I need to find a way to justify that these variables really explain the outcome. Hence thought choosing `p-value` might be best approach which is usually found using `Logistic regression`. Problem with `Feature selection` approach using different algorithms is it returns different subsets with different ranking order of features. Though I find common features across all `FEATURE SELECTION` algorithms, I feel there is no way to justify that these variables really explain the outcome. They might have good predictive power but do are they also responsible for causing a change in the outcome? Hope I made my objective clear. Request you to let me know for any questions

Comment: Your data isn't imbalanced imo, try giving higher class_weight to the class you care about.

Comment: As I am using 'Xgboost',  I make sure to give the parameter 'scale_pos_weight' appropriately based on the ratio of positive and negative class.. Is there any thing else that I can do?

Comment: Are you saying that I should look at accuracy metric as it isn't that bad when it comes to class balance?

Comment: Does your domain imply different cost for misclassifying an example with regards to the two classes (i.e. a false negative being worse than a false positive or vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, we could say that.  It's always costly to let a person with disease as disease free.. Meaning false negative is costly and we should minimize it..

Comment: If you are going to do an xgboost anyway, why don't you keep all your variables ? Most of your questions seems to relates to your use of two models at the same time. Once you sort that, you will be left with the real question about the difference between predictive power and causality... which is quite different than just parameter tuning to get good performance metrics.

Comment: @lcrmorin - What I am trying to do is better listed here with an example. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65909/ml-project-achieve-2-objectives